# How to preserve the leading or trailing space in a .restext resource entry?

Tags: c#, .net, resources

Is there a way to make `resgen.exe` preserve the *leading* or *trailing* spaces in a C# [`.restext` resource file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/resources/creating-resource-files-for-desktop-apps#resources-in-text-files) entry?

For example:

```
PerMonth= / month
NameLabel=Name:
```

(there is a space before the `/` and after the `:`)

When generating the `.resources` file, the spaces are trimmed.

Comment: use a resx file instead.

Comment: or make these format strings.

Comment: Yes, I know the alternatives, my question is really to learn about `.restext` files

Comment: that page you link to explicitly says its ignored.

Comment: `Any blank lines in the text files are considered to be white space and are ignored.`: those labels are not blank lines.